# How to merge Ubuntu partition with unallocated partition with NFTS in the middle?

Tags: partitioning

My partitions are in the following order:

[image]

I want to increase Ubuntu partition space with the unallocated partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer...

First, backup backup backup.

Next make yourself a Ubuntu Live DVD. Read elsewhere on AskUbuntu or Ubuntu.com how to do that if you don't remember how.

Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, start gparted. **Move** your Dropbox D: partition all the way **left**. **Move** your Ubuntu partition all the way **left**. **Resize** your Ubuntu partition to the **right**.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Can I move ubuntu partition to the left of unnalocate and then merge it with unnalocated space?

Comment: You'd still have to move the Dropbox partition. ps: there's no such thing as merge, just move/resize/copy/paste/delete. Cheers, Al

Comment: I just noticed that you don't have a linux swap partition. You'd have to leave a little space for that too, and then edit your /etc/fstab. Make swap 1-1.5 size RAM, unless you've got a super large amount of RAM. Cheers, Al